# Regex to Exclude something and bulk rename files

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to rename all files of a directory, remove parts of files names excluding some parts.

for example:

> ```
> Before --> After
> ```
>
> file1: Something S01E01 Hello There Guys.srt --> S01E01.srt
>
> file2: Something_else S03E22 Good.bye.srt --> S03E22.srt
>
> etc.

I tried following code in powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace "Something",""}
Get-ChildItem | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace "Good.bye",""}
Get-ChildItem | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace "Something_else",""}
Get-ChildItem | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace " Hello(.*?)\.srt",".srt"}
Get-ChildItem | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace " ",""}
```

Any idea about the right regex code instead of hardcoding to exclude "SxxExx.srt" Part of file name and remove the other parts of name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a pattern like this:

```
(S\d{2}E\d{2})
```

to match and capture the `S01E01` part.

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {($_.BaseName -replace '^.*(S\d{2}E\d{2}).*$','$1') + $_.Extension}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
\b[A-Z][0-9]+[A-Z][0-9]+\b\s*|\.srt
```

or,

```
\b[A-Z][0-9]+[A-Z][0-9]+\b\s*|\.srt[^\r\n]*
```

or some similar expression being replaced with an empty string might be somewhat close.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/KaQ7rR/1/)

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/ra6iCU/1/)